# Using nginx in front of php-fpm via docker-compose, why does the php-fpm container only work if named "app"?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I tried to create a Docker service like this:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
    app:
        image: php:8.2-fpm
        working_dir: "/var/www"
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html   
        networks:
            - internal
    nginx:
        restart: always
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./src:/var/www/html
        depends_on:
            - app
        networks:
            - internal

networks:
    internal:
        name: internal
```

```bash
$ docker-compose up -d        
[+] Running 3/3
 ✔ Network internal          Created 0.1s 
 ✔ Container my-php-app-1    Started 0.5s 
 ✔ Container my-php-nginx-1  Started
   
$ curl "http://localhost:8080"
{"message": "Hello World!"}
```

But when I change the `app` container to `apiapp` it got a problem:

```yaml
services:
    apiapp:
        image: php:8.2-fpm
        working_dir: "/var/www"
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html   
        networks:
            - internal
    nginx:
        restart: always
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./src:/var/www/html
        depends_on:
            - apiapp
        networks:
            - internal

networks:
    internal:
        name: internal
```

```bash
$ docker-compose up -d
[+] Running 3/3
 ✔ Network internal           Created 0.0s 
 ✔ Container my-php-apiapp-1  Started 0.5s 
 ✔ Container my-php-nginx-1   Started 0.9s 
$ curl "http://localhost:8080"
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

---

I remove my service first and then type `docker-compose up -d` so I assume that `my-php-app-1` has nothing to do with `my-php-apiapp-1`, but I really don't know why the container name matters.

I tried to find ""app" container on Docker", but the [Compose FAQs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/faq/) and [Key features and use cases of Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/features-uses/) are not really helpful for my question...

---

The Nginx setting file is basically from [a post on qiita](https://qiita.com/shir01earn/items/f236c8280bb745dd6fb4#nginx-%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90):

```
# https://qiita.com/shir01earn/items/f236c8280bb745dd6fb4
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return 404;
        }
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_pass app:9000; 
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location / {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php /index.php?$query_string =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't think I have application servers that may reverse-proxied by Nginx since I only install Nginx on Docker and stop all the other services. In addition, I closed all my runtime applications (like node or rails) on my host that may listen to the 8080 port.

Comment: Eh. I think I misread the question -- I was reading it as "do I really need this separate container?", whereas AFAICT what you mean to ask is "do I  really need this separate container to have this specific name?"; I've modified the title to be  better focused on the is-the-name-special real question.

Comment: Is the `app` name mentioned in your Nginx configuration somewhere, maybe in a `fastcgi_pass` line?  There is nothing special in Docker about a container that happens to be named `app`.

Comment: Show your nginx config

Comment: I added my nginx config on the question, which is basically from [a post on qiita](https://qiita.com/shir01earn/items/f236c8280bb745dd6fb4#nginx-%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90)

Comment: Hmm, I found the container name _matters_ because it affects `fastcgi_pass` on the nginx config, as @DavidMaze mentioned. I don't exactly know why it affected, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your Nginx configuration says

```
fastcgi_pass app:9000;
```

that forwards the request, using the FastCGI protocol, to port 9000 on whatever the host name `app` resolves to.

In a Compose context, the service names

```yaml
services:
  app: { ... }
  nginx: { ... }
```

resolve as host names, assuming the services have compatible `networks:`.  (Also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.)

If you want to rename the `app` container to something else, you need to change that `fastcgi_pass` line to match as well.  If the Nginx configuration sees a host name that doesn't exist, you can get a startup-time error, which is why you get a "connection refused" error in your example.